# macOS MIDI Driver CFPlugin fails on kIOReturnExclusiveAccess and 2 devices shown in MIDI Studio

Tags: macos, driver, midi

I'm trying to write a custom USB MIDI driver for macOS. I found a few projects online that are based on some old Apple Sample code, one example linked below.

https://github.com/ysalathe/GenericUSBMIDI

The project seems sensible and works to an extent, but I'm having a problem with it. I hoped someone with experience of the macOS CFPlugin based MIDI driver system might be able to help me...

Steps to recreate issue:

1. Copy the project's product (GenericUSBDriver.plugin) to ~/Library/Audio/MIDI Drivers
2. Connect my MIDI device via USB
3. Open Audio MIDI setup and select show MIDI studio
4. MIDI studio now shows an icon with the name from my MIDI device's USB descriptor. However, my log shows that my driver failed in USBDevice::OpenAndConfigure when USBDeviceOpen() returns kIOReturnExclusiveAccess (USBDevice.cpp line: 189).

   ```
   require_noerr((*mPluginIntf)->USBDeviceOpen(mPluginIntf), errexit);
   ```
5. Then after clicking 'Rescan MIDI' my driver loads successfully and a 2nd icon appears in MIDI studio with the driver specified name, but the original icon from step 4 persists. So, I now have 2 icons representing the attached device in MIDI Studio.

Googling things like: 'USBDeviceOpen() kIOReturnExclusiveAccess MIDI' gets various 'Apple Mailing Lists' hits around a decade old, but with no solutions.

It seems to me the standard Apple USB MIDI driver is grabbing my device and causing my driver to fail with kIOReturnExclusiveAccess on USBDeviceOpen(). Then after clicking 'Rescan MIDI' the Apple driver has let go, which allows my driver to load.

My device has an asynchronous USB audio interface, and a MIDI interface with 2 bidirectional ports.

My main question is...

**How can I get the Apple MIDI system to select my driver after matching on USB VID/PID instead of the standard Apple driver?**

but also...

**Does anyone know of any docs or books that can help me? Is there a newer/ better way perhaps?**

**My driver renames the MIDI ports to something more intuitive for our users, macOS seems to ignore the names in the jack descriptors unlike Windows. Is there another way to do this?**

I've been reading the book "OS X and iOS Kernel Programming", but while being very interesting hasn't shed any light on this problem. I can get their USB driver example to match on my USB device's MIDI interface and load, but there seems no obvious way for that to then influence the CFPlugin choice.

Comment: If you want to prevent the Apple driver from attaching, change your device's firmware to report a vendor-specific interface.

Comment: A good suggestion! Sadly, I neglected to mention I have USB audio interfaces on my USB device as well. Setting bDeviceClass to 'Vendor Specific' prevents macOS loading the standard driver for the audio. I will update my question. I would also like macOS to use the standard MIDI driver if my driver isn't present. Interestingly, setting 'Vendor Specific' stops the default MIDI driver loading just like you say, but once I copy my driver to '~/Library/Audio/MIDI Drivers' and start MIDI Studio I get the same problem as before. Maybe there is more to this than I first suspected...